# What did Mat say in the Old Tongue?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, a-memory-of-light

In chapter 27 of *A Memory of Light*, Mat says:

> *Laero lendhe an indemela*

Min thinks it was:

> *...Something about a flag.*

When questioned about it he says:

> *It's a saying of the Fallen Army of Kardia*

***What does that saying mean?***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to *[The Wheel of Time Companion](https://books.google.com/books?id=qhaSCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA394&ots=-1hSfX4XJY&dq=Fallen%20Army%20of%20Kardia&pg=PA394#v=onepage&q=Fallen%20Army%20of%20Kardia&f=false)*, it means: "The enemy's flag has fallen"

> ***Laero lendhae an indemela.*** An Old Tongue saying of the Fallen Army of Kardia meaning "The enemy's flag has fallen."  Mat recalled it
>   from his old memories.